# On upgrading to angular 5.2 from 2.4 getting ng build error cannot find @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, angular5, kendo-ui-angular2

I have upgraded to Angular 5.2 and have installed npm node modules twice. After ng build i am getting error as Cannot find module '@progress/kendo-angu
lar-dateinputs' [image: error image]

after installing that @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs , i m getting weired errors as. i have not used anywhere kendo-angular-dateinputs as previously also before update i did not had this module and my app was working fine before upgrade. any idea of why this is or how to solve this?

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/filtering/shared-filtering.module.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs' in 'C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid
\dist\es\filtering'
resolve '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs' in 'C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\filtering'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\package.json (relative path: ./dist/es/filtering)

    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\package.json (relative path: ./dist/es/filt
ering)
    resolve as module
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\filtering\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src
        using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src
        using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\filtering\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\node_modules]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
 @ ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/filtering/shared-filtering.module.js 5:0-62
 @ ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/filtering/cell/row-filtering.module.js
 @ ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/main.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/rendering/body.module.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs' in 'C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid
\dist\es\rendering'
resolve '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs' in 'C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\rendering'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\package.json (relative path: ./dist/es/rendering)

    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\package.json (relative path: ./dist/es/rend
ering)
    resolve as module
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\rendering\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src
        using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src
        using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\package.json (relative path: ./src/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs doesn't exist
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\rendering\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\node_modules]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.ts]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs.js]
[C:\Projects\copy of project for testing\src\@progress\kendo-angular-inputs]
 @ ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/rendering/body.module.js 19:0-70
 @ ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/main.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

i dowloaded the @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs latest version from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs and deleted the npm node modules. and then reinstalled a fresh node modules by npm i and after ng build got away from this long weired error.